# What is meant specifically by "history" in history of science and mathematics?

Tags: discussion

So I recently asked the following:

[What did Sommerfeld mean by Bohr's magic wand?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/10976/what-did-sommerfeld-mean-by-bohrs-magic-wand)

While I am aware of possible vulgarity. I try my best not to divulge into it. However, after the comment "I'm not sure if this site is the right place for this question." And now a downvote I would like to know:

What specific "History" was in the mind of the community? I understand this may be some kind of borderline case but still this makes it worth clarifying.

Comment: I don't think there is any definitive answer to the question, as posed. However, I think that, in the specific context of the linked post, one can say that speculation about potential jokes in old scientific quotes is perhaps not of great interest to many visitors of this site.